# SQL Query to select Banner for each page

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to get following things.

There are Banners assigned to category.
No of banners is dynamic for each category.

Suppose I have 100 Products in one category and 3 banners in that category. Then it will be like as following.

Page 1: 1-10 Products and Banner1

Page 2: 11-20 Products and Banner2

Page 3: 21-30 Products and Banner3

Page 4: 31-40 Products and Banner1

Page 5: 31-40 Products and Banner2

Page 6: 41-50 Products and Banner3

**.
.**

I need a query to select one banner in each page.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

**Database Scheme for reference**:

dbo.Category (Id int, CategoryName Varchar(100))

dbo.Product (Id int, ProductName varchar(100), Description varhcar(max), ImageLink varchar(100))

dbo.Category_Product_Mapping (CategoryId int, ProdcutId int)

dbo.Banner(Id int, ImageLink varchar(100), DisplayOrder int, CategoryId int)

Comment: Can you give us your table schema and sample data?

Comment: Banner# = ((page#-1) modulo 3) +1

Comment: @dnoeth : how did you get it so quick? :D

Comment: @PrabhatG: been there, done that :-)

Comment: @dnoeth Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
create table #product (productid int)
    insert into #product values (9),(19),(29)
    ,(39),(49),(59),(69),(79),(89),(99),(100),(111)
    ,(121)

DECLARE @rangesize INT = 10
DECLARE @numberofBanner INT = 3
DECLARE @Margin INT = @rangesize * @numberofBanner

SELECT productid
    ,CASE 
        WHEN productid < @Margin
            THEN (productid / @rangesize) + 1
        ELSE (productid / @rangesize) % @numberofBanner + 1
        END bannerid
FROM #product

DROP TABLE #product
```

Alternatively,you can create one temp table like below

```
    create table #bannerrange (FromID int,ToID int,Bannerid int)
    --then join with product table

    drop table #product
```